# Docker --device vs -v in docker run

Tags: docker, mount, docker-run

I was trying stuff with Docker today and by mistake, I mounted my `/dev/dri` folder inside the container with `-v` instead of `--device`. However, this worked the same.

Therefore, my question is: what's the difference between `--device` and `-v`? And when should I use `--device` instead of `-v`?